# What are differences between the singular and plural argument in 'dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta'?

Tags: python, python-dateutil, relativedelta

Excerpt from the description of [`dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html),

> year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond:
>
> ```
> Absolute information (argument is singular); adding or subtracting a
> relativedelta with absolute information does not perform an aritmetic
> operation, but rather REPLACES the corresponding value in the
> original datetime with the value(s) in relativedelta.
> ```
>
> years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds:
>
> ```
> Relative information, may be negative (argument is plural); adding
> or subtracting a relativedelta with relative information performs
> the corresponding aritmetic operation on the original datetime value
> with the information in the relativedelta.
> ```

I can see the differences from the following example when it comes to adding and subtracting.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> str(now)
'2016-05-23 22:32:48.427269'
>>> singular = relativedelta(month=3)
>>> plural = relativedelta(months=3)

# subtracting 
>>> str(now - singular)             # replace the corresponding value in the original datetime with the value(s) in relativedelta
'2016-03-23 22:32:48.427269'
>>> str(now - plural)               # perform the corresponding aritmetic operation on the original datetime value with the information in the relativedelta.
'2016-02-23 22:32:48.427269'

# adding
>>> str(now + singular)             # replace the corresponding value in the original datetime with the value(s) in relativedelta
'2016-03-23 22:32:48.427269'
>>> str(now + plural)               # perform the corresponding aritmetic operation on the original datetime value with the information in the relativedelta.
'2016-08-23 22:32:48.427269'
```

Beside this, what are other differences between the singular and plural argument in `relativedelta`?

Comment: What do you mean by "other differences"? You seem to have captured the overall difference pretty effectively.

Comment: @Paul, I just want to make sure I understand well the differences such that I won't make mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singular arguments are absolute information, essentially you can think of `relativedelta(month=3)` to mean "the month of March, relative to whatever date and time it is applied to" (i.e. replace the `month` keyword). This is not amenable to operations like multiplication and division, so these operations have no effect on absolute information:

```
>>> relativedelta.relativedelta(month=3) * 3
relativedelta(month=3)
```

Plural arguments are relative *offsets*, so they are saying, "give me this many months after/before the date". Since these are an offset, they are amenable to multiplication and division:

```
>>> relativedelta.relativedelta(months=3) * 3
relativedelta(months=9)
```

A good example of where this is used would be in the `tzrange` class, which uses `relativedelta` to emulate the behavior of POSIX-style TZ strings. You can see [this test](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/dateutil/test/test_tz.py#L907), which uses the following object:

```
tz.tzrange('EST', -18000, 'EDT', -14400,
       start=relativedelta(hours=+2, month=4, day=1, weekday=SU(+1)),
       end=relativedelta(hours=+1, month=10, day=31, weekday=SU(-1)))
```

This constructs a time zone equivalent to `'EST5EDT'`, where the `start` relativedelta is added to any date in a given year to find the start of DST for that year, and `end` is added to any date in a given year to find the end of DST for that year.

Breaking it down:

- `month` gives you a date in April
- `day` starts you out at the first of the month
- `weekday=SU(+1)` gives you the first Sunday on or after the specified date (this is applied after the `month` and `day` parameters, so when the `day` is set to 1, you get the first Sunday of the month).
- `hours=+2` - this will give you 2 hours after all the other stuff has been applied. Probably in this case `hour=2` makes more sense for demonstrating the concept, though, since where these `relativedelta`s actually gets used I think strips out the time portion first (giving a date at midnight), so this is really trying to encode 2AM.